# What property of cycles can disprove this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If there exists a cycle containing vertices $u,v$ and a cycle containing vertices $v,w$, then there exists a cycle containing $u,w$.

Obviously, there is a very easy graph to draw that can prove this statement but my prof said that there is a counterexample to this statement so there is some way to draw a cycle that can disprove this statement but I can't figure it out. A property of cycles is that each vertex has a degree of 2 so how is it possible to have a graph where there is a cycle containing $u,v$ and a cycle containing $v,w$ but not one which contains $u,w$ within the same graph? Is there another property that I have to consider to draw the graph?

Comment: Just consider two squares having a common vertex ($v$), with $u$ on the first square and $w$ on the second. However, you may find a $u-w$ cycle iff the $u-v$ cycle and the $v-w$ cycle intersect at two distinct vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If vertex $v$ is a [cutpoint](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArticulationVertex.html) while $u$ and $w$ belong to different [blocks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Block.html) containing $v$ then this graph is a counterexample. The simplest one is $G = K_1 + 2K_2$, that is $$G = (\{\,1, 2, 3, 4, 5\,\}, \{\,\{\,1, 2\,\}, \{\,1, 3\,\}, \{\,1, 4\,\}, \{\,1, 5\,\}, \{\,2, 3\,\}, \{\,4, 5\,\}\,\})$$
for $v = 1$, $u = 2$ and $w = 4$.